# HQL select query with where condition is not showing same result

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am being redirected to always an error page, when I submit my login form.

Checked following:

1. Username and password submitting in jsp form are exactly same in DB. So I can confirm that the user exist in DB.
2. Hardcoded the values in java class to check whether it is working with correct credentials, it worked fine.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">bmmblr</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Drop and recreate the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<!-- classes annotated @Entity -->
<mapping class="com.bmm.inventory.bean.User"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
public int getUserbyCredentials(String userName, String passWord) {
    //User user = new User();
    System.out.println("Form values:"+userName+"  "+passWord);
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Query Params:"+userName+"  "+passWord);
    Query query = session.createQuery(
            "select u.userName,u.passWord from User u where u.userName=:userName and u.passWord=:passWord");
    query.setString("userName", userName);
    query.setString("passWord", passWord);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> list =(List<User>) query.list();
    System.out.println("Result:"+list+"  "+list.size());
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return list.size();
}
```

Action Class:

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Entering execute method of Login Action"+this.getUserName()+"  "+this.getPassWord());
    SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) ctx.getAttribute("SessionFactory");
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(sf);
    int userDB = userDAO.getUserbyCredentials(this.getUserName(), this.getPassWord());
    System.out.println("User Obj: "+userDB);
    if(userDB < 1)
        return "ERROR";
    else {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Below is the output printed in console when I enter right credentials.

```
Form values : test  abc123

Hibernate: select user0_.user_usa_name as col_0_0_, user0_.user_password as col_1_0_ from bmmblr.USERS user0_ where user0_.user_usa_name=? and user0_.user_password=?

Count : 0
```

Bean class:

```
package com.bmm.inventory.bean;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="USERS")
public class User {


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    public String getUserStatusCode() {
        return userStatusCode;
    }
    public void setUserStatusCode(String userStatusCode) {
        this.userStatusCode = userStatusCode;
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(Long iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="userIdSeq", sequenceName="user_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="userIdSeq")
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name="user_usa_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="user_password")
    private String passWord;

    @Column(name="user_location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name="user_created_dt")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name="user_status_cd")
    private String userStatusCode;




}
```

Comment: please add the User entity and the row from database that contains the credentials (with column names)

Comment: `SQL> select user_usa_name,user_password from users where user_usa_name='test' and user_password='abc123';
USER_USA_NAME   USER_PASSWORD
----------------  ----------------
test     abc123`

Comment: what does this print? System.out.println("Result:"+list+"  "+list.size());

Comment: Result:[] 
and 
Size: 0

Comment: And when you invoke following? select user_usa_name,user_password from bmmblr.users where user_usa_name='test' and user_password='abc123'. Do you get the row?

Comment: yes I do get a row.

Comment: so you say when you hardcode values in this method getUserbyCredentials.. you get the row right?

Comment: Yes, I do get it when I hard code the credentials.

Comment: did you debug and check what is actually under this.getUserName(), this.getPassWord()? Maybe you should trim() before passing

Comment: I have included a sysout to see what am I getting in them. I could see them correctly. I just tried trimming still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Im quite surprised that you dont get an error here as you are using projection in your query but expect a List of User entities:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
            "select u.userName,u.passWord from User u where u.userName=:userName and u.passWord=:passWord");
    query.setString("userName", userName);
    query.setString("passWord", passWord);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> list =(List<User>) query.list();
```

**Solution 1**

Select entire User entity in your query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
            "select u from User u where u.userName=:userName and u.passWord=:passWord");
    query.setString("userName", userName);
    query.setString("passWord", passWord);
```

**Solution 2**

Expect List of Object[] and then extract username and password one by one:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
            "select u.userName,u.passWord from User u where u.userName=:userName and u.passWord=:passWord");
    query.setString("userName", userName);
    query.setString("passWord", passWord);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> list =(List<Object[]>) query.list();

    Object firstRow = list[0];      
    userName = (String)firstRow [0];
    passwd = (String)firstRow [1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could achieve this without the parameters setting using : symbols. I used the + symbols to frame the query that worked.

```
// something like below

Query query = session.createQuery(
            "select * from User u where u.userName="+this.userName+"and u.passWord="+this.passWord");
```